# Anyway to setup traefik to feed matomo automatically?

Tags: traefik, matomo, piwiktracker

With a self hosted instance like matomo, and a smart edge router like traefik, I was hoping to find some automated solution for analytics via traefik configuration instead of injecting JavaScript into each hosted service on my docker based server.

It seems to me the best way to track usage in the backend, instead of relying on 'the goodness of the browser', especially with ad blockers targeting matomo.

Has anyone tackled this in any fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with Log Analytics: https://matomo.org/log-analytics-/
See also: https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-log-analytics

Comment: Never pursued this, so apologies for never responding. Marking as done.